# Rowspan and heigth top column in bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

How can I do in bootstrap such a grid:

```
<table border=1>
  <tr>
  <td style="height: 30px">aaaa</td><td rowspan="2">bbbb</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  <td style="font-size: 9px">cccccccc</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/68anykfe/1/

Is this possible?

I tried:

```
<div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-9">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-12" style="height: 60px">aaaaa</div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-12">ccccc</div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-3">
                bbbbb
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

In this example i would like "bbbbbb" have aligned to bottom.

Comment: Not sure if I understand you right but try adding vertical-align:bottom to .col-lg-3

Comment: @StefanNeuenschwander yes, but still this is not bottom of first div.row

Comment: If you want to address the first .row use: .row:first-child

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you are asking for? https://jsfiddle.net/eye4ytq2/8/

```
<div class="col-xs-2 border">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-6">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12  border" style="height: 60px">aaaaa</div>
        <div class="col-xs-12  border">ccccc</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6  border" style="height: 81px">
      bbbbb
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```